# How do I import vue examples into a standalone html file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my quest to learn Vue I'm trying to create a page with tabs based on one of the Vue examples, https://vuejsexamples.com/a-slim-tab-component-for-vue-js/, but I must be missing something obvious as I get a syntax error on the line

```html
import * as Tabs from 'vue-slim-tabs';
```

when I open it in chrome

```
tabs01.html:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

I am just viewing it as a local file file:///C:/Users/USERX/Documents/git-projects/vue/tabs/tabs01.html as I'm just trying to learn the basics. I suspect I'm missing something very obvious here as neither the import line nor the script tag import works.

tabs01.html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tabbing test 01</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <template>
      <tabs>
        <tab title="Vue">
          This is Vue
        </tab>
        <tab title="React">
          This is React
        </tab>
        <tab title="Svelte">
          This is Svelte
        </tab>
      </tabs>
    </template>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slim-tabs@0.3.0/dist/vue-slim-tabs.js"></script>

  <script>
    import * as Tabs from 'vue-slim-tabs';
    Vue.use(Tabs);
    const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return {}
            },
          });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems like the root cause of my problem is that I tried to use an example that requires the use of the full vue app framework or transpiling. I switched to one of the tab examples from awesome-vue (https://github.com/cristijora/vue-tabs) and that works out of the box with a standalone html-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the global variable `vueSlimTabs` to reference the plugin instead of importing. This global variable is created when the vue-slim-tabs.js source is loaded as a non-module script. Example:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tabbing test 01</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slim-tabs@0.3.0/themes/default.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <template>
          <tabs>
            <tab title="Vue">
              This is Vue
            </tab>
            <tab title="React">
              This is React
            </tab>
            <tab title="Svelte">
              This is Svelte
            </tab>
          </tabs>
        </template>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slim-tabs@0.3.0/dist/vue-slim-tabs.js"></script>
  <script>
    Vue.use(vueSlimTabs);
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data() {
        return {}
      },
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

*If* vue-slip-tabs was setup as an ES6 module, you could import with something like this:

```
<script type="module">  
import * from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slim-tabs@0.3.0/dist/vue-slim-tabs.js'  
//...
</script>
```

However, it is currently setup as UMD module only. As such, importing as an ES6 module requires transpiling, which is done by most vue/webpack cli setups. In that case the source gets transformed before being loaded by browser.

Answer (score 1):

Is this compiled vue or have you just opened your file in chrome as its written above?

You can't use import without compiling vue. Most of the simple example files use vues simple string template format that you can open directly in a browser.

To use import, you need to compile vue first and then open in a browser.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: The op's question is not a single file vue component. Also, it is possible to use ES6 import in most modern browsers _without_ transpiling.